# How to use trained Keras CNN model for prediction with new unlabeled data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, time-series, conv-neural-network

The temperature prediction time series tutorial on Google colab provides a good walk through on setting up the training, validation, and test performance for various models. How can I use this trained multi_conv_model to run a temperature prediction with new unlabeled data. Specificallly looking for how to call the Keras predict function with a dataframe of inputs only.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/structured_data/time_series.ipynb

```
CONV_WIDTH = 3
multi_conv_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Shape [batch, time, features] => [batch, CONV_WIDTH, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -CONV_WIDTH:, :]),
    # Shape => [batch, 1, conv_units]
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256, activation='relu', kernel_size=(CONV_WIDTH)),
    # Shape => [batch, 1,  out_steps*features]
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features,
                          kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros()),
    # Shape => [batch, out_steps, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features])
])

history = compile_and_fit(multi_conv_model, multi_window)

IPython.display.clear_output()

multi_val_performance['Conv'] = multi_conv_model.evaluate(multi_window.val)
multi_performance['Conv'] = multi_conv_model.evaluate(multi_window.test, verbose=0)
multi_window.plot(multi_conv_model)
```

Here's what I tried but it is not giving meaningful 5 period forecast:

```
predict_inputs_df = test_df[:20] # or some other input data points
predict_inputs_df =  (predict_inputs_df - train_mean) / train_std
predictions = conv_model(tf.stack([np.array(predict_inputs_df)]))
predictions
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `conv_model.evaluate(tf.stack([np.array(predict_inputs_df)]))`.

That should give you some results.